# ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I'm able to run the spark examples on the cluster with no issues.
Now Why I am getting this error??

ERROR cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Disconnected from Spark cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be due to some incompatible installation with spark. Please check the compatible version of other setup. As the same error I was also getting.